# Trying to align 4 divs side by side in css

Tags: css, css-float, html

I have 4 divs in a wrapper div and I'm trying align them. The first 2 align, but the other 2 go below and no where I want em to go no matter what I try!

**Wrapper Div**

```
#contentbk{

margin:auto;
width:90%;
background-color:#000;
padding-top:2%;
padding-bottom:1%;
text-align:center;
height:300px;
    }
```

**4 divs within wrapper**

```
    #contentbk div { 
    height:100px; 
    width:10%; 
    float:left;        
    }
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net of your problem?

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/CDcGH. You have to set `overflow: hidden` to the parent element whenever you have floated children. That way the parent will 'know' the children are there.

Comment: overflow didn't change anything.

Comment: Nevermind...I had 2 closing tags after one div in my html :O